# как использовать переменную в другом файле flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

На странице В, в классе В есть следующий код -

```
class B extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var result = '';
                  var url = "http://10.0.101.141:6113/api/Cashier/authenticate";
                  final response = await http.post(
                    Uri.parse(url),
                    headers: <String, String>{
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    },
                    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                      'login': _textEditingController.text,
                      'password': _passEditingController.text
                    }),
                  );
                  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
                    result = jsonEncode(response.body); //ВОТ ЭТУ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ МНЕ НУЖНО КАК ТО ПЕРЕТАЩИТЬ В ФАЙЛ "A"
                    print(result);
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                  } else {
                    print('err');
                  }

                  //
                  // print(_textEditingController.text);
                  // print(_passEditingController.text);
                },
                child: Text('sdfsdfs'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  }
}
```

Мне нужно использовать переменную result в Файле A, с классом А -

```
class A extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var sum = int.parse(text);
                  const url = "http://10.0.101.141:6113/api/transaction/createtransaction";
                  final token = ''; //ВОТ ТУТ МНЕ НУЖНО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ
                  try {
                    final response = await http.post (
                        Uri.parse(url),
                        headers: <String, String>{
                          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                          "Authorization": 'Bearer $token'
                        },
                        body: jsonEncode(<String, int> {
                          'amount': sum
                        })
                    );
                    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                      Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Qr()));
                      var res = await response.body;
                      print(res);
                    } else{
                      var res = response.statusCode;
                      print(res);
                    }
                  } catch (error) {
                    print(error);
                  }
                },
                child: Text('sdfsdfs'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
  }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать? Я попытался предоставить всю необходимую информацию, извините, если много лишнего кода, я только что набросал эту не большую конструкцию, но она передает смысл проблемы

Любой помощи буду рад!

Answer (score 1):

Профессиональным решением этой и других сопутствующих проблем является продуманная архитектура приложения. Используйте архитектурные паттерны. Когда мне дали разработку мобильного приложения на flutter, то был выбран шаблон `MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)`. Логика следующая:

- Есть `Model`, отвечает за то, как выглядят данные, то есть, если работаете с пользователями, создаете класс UserModel и там храните его поля и т.д.
- Есть `View`, он отвечает за отображение, это и есть ваши экраны, где отрисовываются элементы.
- И связывает их объект `ViewModel`, в котором хранится логика. В этом классе должны реализовываться все функции, отвечающие за логику. Туда как раз и вынесете события нажатия кнопок и отправки запроса. И тут же будут складываться данные результата запроса и т.п. Если на экране должен отображаться список чего-то, то список моделей должен лежать внутри ViewModel и из него экран должен этот список получать, чтобы отрисовать. Можете создать один объект ViewModel и передать его двум экранам в конструкторе, таким образом ViewModel сохранит данные и любой экран сможет их прочитать.

В реализации помогла библиотека `stacked`.
Вот так выглядит создание `MaterialApp`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // позволяем приложению только портретную ориентацию экрана
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

    return ViewModelBuilder<AppLanguageViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => locator<AppLanguageViewModel>(),
      builder: (context, AppLanguageViewModel viewModel, _) => MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: Routes.loading,
        routes: {
          Routes.loading: (context) => LoadingScreen(languageViewModel: viewModel),
          Routes.auth: (context) => AuthScreen(languageViewModel: viewModel),
          Routes.main: (context) => MainScreen(languageViewModel: viewModel),
          Routes.schedule: (context) => ScheduleScreen(),
          Routes.notification: (context) => NotificationScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Здесь `locator` - это глобальная переменная: `final locator = GetIt.instance;`. Объект `GetIt` из библиотеки `get_it`. Он помогает регистрировать singleton объекты. Вот пример:

```
final locator = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> setupLocator() async {
  // Здесь регистрируем синглтоны

  // Сервисы
  locator.registerSingleton(new LocalStorageService());
  locator.registerSingleton(new TokenService());
  locator.registerSingleton(new AppLanguageService());

  // Глобальные ViewModel
  locator.registerSingleton<AppLanguageViewModel>(new AppLanguageViewModel());

  // Для утилит
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => new Random());
}
```

Далее, во входной функции `main()` нужно вызвать функцию настройки `locator'а` до запуска приложения:

```
// locator - объект, который помогает манипулировать синглтонами
await setupLocator();

runApp(MyApp());
```

Здесь в строчке `ViewModelBuilder<AppLanguageViewModel>.reactive` создаётся `AppLanguageViewModel`, который отвечает за функционал переключения языка приложения и он передаётся в конструкторы экранов, где он должен использоваться. Далее уже вызывайте необходимые функции и используйте требующиеся данные, работая с одним экземпляром `ViewModel` на разных экранах.

Пример того как используется `ViewModel` на экране:

```
MainSwitchLanguageButtonView(
    onChangeLanguage: (key) =>
        languageViewModel.setLanguageByKey(key),
    currentLanguage: languageViewModel.current)
```